# Rake task creates CSV and then upload to S3. How?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I have a rake task that creates a CSV file.  Right now I am storing this file into my /tmp folder (I am using Heroku).  This CSV file is not associated with any model, it's just some data I pull from several APIs, combined with some data from my models.

I would like to download this file from Heroku, but this seems not possible. So, my question is: Which gem am I trying to look for in order to upload that file to Amazon S3? I have seen gems like Paperclip, but that seems to be associated with a model, and that is not my case. I just want to upload that CSV file that I will have in /tmp, into my Amazon S3 bucket.

Thanks

Comment: Any luck with either of the posted solutions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [aws-s3 gem](https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3)

```
S3Object.store('filename_in_s3.txt', open("source_file.tmp"), 'bucket_name')
```

You should define the exact path of your tmp file, for example:

```
open("#{Rails.root}/tmp/source_file.tmp")
```

Answer (score 0):

[CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) can directly interface your Ruby application with S3 directly via the [Fog](https://github.com/fog/fog) library. Rather than operating on the model level, CarrierWave utilizes a `Uploader` class where you can cull from across your APIs and datasources, which is precisely what you're trying to accomplish.